# Why is this considered a complete answer?

Tags: discussion, homework-and-exercises, answers

Recently, [an answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/361486/45808) was deleted for being a complete answer to a [homework-and-exercises](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework-and-exercises) question.

However, since I did not give the final value of the wavelength, why is this "a complete answer"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *did* give the final value. If the answer is $4$, and I write $2+2$ and leave it unevaluated, I gave the final value. An arithmetical computation is not a meaningful part of solving a problem, and if that is the only step that separates you from the answer, then the problem is done. Sorry but you don't have a case here -- the best you can do is to forget about this and move on.

Comment: out of curiosity: is posting a question in the meta forum the only way to ask clarifications on such specific closures?  Should there a realistic opportunity for the poster to modify her/his question or answer so it can comply with the policy?  In most other instances of closure or deletion, the  decision is the result of a vote, and while some votes carry more weights than other, it takes time to accumulate enough votes to close or delete, thereby usually affording the poster time to consider comments on a question or answer and make (or not) adjustments.

Comment: I suppose my point is: is it practical to suggest either editing or at least self-deletion by the poster before deletion by the moderators.

Answer (score 1):

The comment that [ACuriousMind](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/50583/acuriousmind) (ACM) left when deleting your question is,

> I'm deleting this in accordance with [our homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/25301). Please do not give complete or near-complete answers to homework-like questions

This comment is basically the same thing that is written in the homework policy under the heading *Why don't you provide a complete answer to homework questions?*

So even if you wanted to argue that you did not give a *complete* answer (which I'd agree that AFT's assessment is correct), one could even more easily argue that you gave a *near-complete* answer that is treated the same as a complete answer to this type of question.